# FancyBox2 and Droid 2.3.4 - Not able to scroll

Tags: android, jquery, css, iframe, fancybox-2

I've been struggling with this. When on my Droid 2.3.4 and viewing content via iFrame in Fancybox2, I'm not getting scroll bars. I've seen many potential solutions, but all have no affect. All other browsers, including iPhone 5 and iPad.. work. I'm only having trouble with my Droid.

Here is the calling function.

```
$('.various').fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '95%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            locked : false
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried various overflow:scrolls or the !important fix, but nothing works. I've even tried using iScroll, but nothing is providing any scrolling.

Please let me know if you have any ideas. I'm about to the point of putting special handling for Droid devices to open a separate page.. but obviously, I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with my relic of a phone, Android 2.3.x doesn't support secondary scroll bars, only the scroll bar of the browser itself.

This is a pretty major issue because Android 2.3.x currently still accounts for more than half of the active Android devices.

The only solution is to allow your fancyBox to expand beyond the height of the viewport so that the user can view the rest of the content using the main scroll bar.

Comment: Ouch.. was worried about that. I'm putting handling now that will open overlay as a full window. I hate this solution, but I'm not making any headway otherwise.